# find mle on a list of functions in R

Tags: r

I write a for loop code based (see below), in order to find the mle of a function list. However, the search for the likelihood of these functions is so hard. So, I want to pass the code to mcapply style function to run each iteration on different cores.

code

```
fitted.c<-list()
for(i in 1:length(functions.c)){
fitted.c[[i]]<-find.mle(functions.c[[i]], p.start.c)
}
```

in where functions.c is a list of functions.

Any suggestion will be appreciated
Best, Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly thing, just did:

```
mclapply(functions.c, function(i){
p.start.c <- c(0.1, 0, 0.01, 0.01)
fit<-find.mle(i, p.start.c)
```

and work perfectly

Best to all